# Repackage war without using mvn package running verify only on few dependent projects

Tags: java, maven, deployment, continuous-integration, war

Hi My Dependency structure is as follows:

```
--A
---B
 ---C
 ---D
---E
----F
----G
-----H
---I
```

-> [A] is a web project and will produce a war.

-> If I change [F][G] and only build them

**->** How do I recreate the war for project [A] using build result of [F] and [G] in minimum possible time?

What are my options other than takari-plugin.

Ok let me explain my whole problem so and my plans on how to approach it in order to solve it.

**Problem**
I have a very complex dependency tree(many developer written sub projects) in my project . Every time a developer makes changes to any of the projects. Mvn verify is run in the parent pom to verify whether user change does not break the environment. 
After mvn verify is a success then the created war is deployed. If everything works fine the changes are kept else developer is given the log report and asked to re-check. And this all process is automated of-course by scripts.

I feel running mvn verify on all projects is a waste of time and an unnecessary operation. So I am looking forward to reducing this time.

My idea for the Time reduction as as follows:

**My Solution**
1) Calculate dependency tree

2) Run mvn verify on only projects in the path between parent pom and projects changed by developer.

I plan on checking this from the dependency tree and then running mvn install on individual projects. But if there is some other way please suggest the fastest possible way in combination and consideration with point 3

3) After this I will run mvn verify in offline mode  and skipping tests on my parent pom so that things are speed-ed up.
(I needed an answer to avoid this step)

I can afford to use offline mode since while calculating dependency tree all dependencies will be downloaded and the current ones are already installed on my local repository.
Now after this step I have my war ready to be deployed.

Is there any flaw in the approach and how do I speed up the 2+3 combination

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Why you mentioned takari-plugin?

Comment: I need to repackage war by rebuilding only some of the dependent projects.
I mentioned takari because I don't want to use it. I don't want to package my jar as takari-jar.

Comment: Have you defined the dependencies correctly? So you can use `mvn -pl project -amd ...` ? Apart from that the packaging type `takari-jar` is only needed to activate the appropriate life cycle and has nothing to do with the resulting packaging type war/jar etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, most versions of Apache Maven will not be able to refer to build artifacts which were produced within the reactor itself. For most installations running most versions of Apache Maven, you will need to first install your WARs dependencies and only then can you safely package the WAR with confidence that you are picking up the new changes in your dependencies.

To achieve this, you should run `mvn -pl :f,:g install ; mvn -pl :a package` which will first push your recent changes into the repository, and then package up your web application. This solution works to build the fewest number of modules in the fewest number of Apache Maven invocations. Good luck!

Comment: Hi can you please give some more details. About what exactly this command does? Precisely how do I specify what projects to install?